# A library management system

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns

Following is my code for a library management system. I am pretty new to OOD and trying to learn it. I am specially looking for ways where any design patterns can be useful here. I tried to make classes so that I follow Single Responsibility principle. Would appreciate any feedback for it.

```
/*
This class is similar to admin with more priviliges
1. Add books
2. remove Books
 */
public class Admin extends Person{

    private String libname;
    Admin(String name, String phoneNo, String address, String libname){
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
        this.libname = libname;
    }

    public void addBook(int id, String author, Genre gen){
        Library.getInstance(libname).addBookItem(id, author, gen);
    }

    public void removeBook(int id){
        Library.getInstance(libname).removeBookItem(id);
    }

}
```

```
public class Book {

    int id;
    String author;
    Genre genre;    // can be converted to enums

}
```

```
/*
1. extends Book class
2. It handles additional fields like reservations
 */


import java.sql.Time;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class BookItem extends Book{

    private LocalTime resStartdate;
    private LocalTime resEndDate;

    BookItem(int id, String author, Genre genre){
        this.id = id;
        this.author = author;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.resStartdate = LocalTime.now();
        this.resEndDate = this.resStartdate;
    }

    public LocalTime getResEndDate() {
        return resEndDate;
    }

    public void setResEndDate(LocalTime resEndDate) {
        this.resEndDate = resEndDate;
    }

    public LocalTime getResStartdate() {
        return resStartdate;
    }

    public void setResStartdate(LocalTime resStartdate) {
        this.resStartdate = resStartdate;
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Catalog {

     static String libName;

//    Catalog(String libName){
//        Catalog.l = Library.getInstance(libName);
//    }

    public int temp(){
        return 0;
    }
    public static List<BookItem> searchByAuthor(String author){
        List<BookItem> result = new ArrayList<>();
        // logic
        List<BookItem> bookItemList = Library.getInstance(libName).bookItemList;
        for(BookItem temp : bookItemList){
            if(temp.author == author){
                result.add(temp);
            }
        }
        printResult(result);
        return result;
    }

    public static List<BookItem> searchByGenre(Genre g){
        List<BookItem> result = new ArrayList<>();
        // logic
        List<BookItem> bookItemList = Library.getInstance(libName).bookItemList;
        for(BookItem temp : bookItemList){
            if(temp.genre == g){
                result.add(temp);
            }
        }
        printResult(result);
        return result;
    }

    private static void printResult(List<BookItem> result){
        if(result.size() == 0){
            System.out.println("No Books Found.");
            return ;
        }
        System.out.println("Following books Found: ");
        for(BookItem item : result) {
            System.out.println("ID:: " + item.id +
                    " Author:: " + item.author +
                    " Genre:: " + item.genre
            );
        }
    }
}
```

```
public enum Genre {

    HORROR,
    SCIFI,
    ROMANTIC,
    FICTION;
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Library {

    String name;

    private static Library instance;

    List<BookItem> bookItemList;

    private Library(String libName){
        this.name = libName;
        bookItemList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static Library getInstance(String libname){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new Library(libname);
            return instance;
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void addBookItem(int id, String author, Genre gen){
        bookItemList.add(new BookItem(id, author, gen));
    }

    public void removeBookItem(int id){

        for(int i = 0;i<bookItemList.size();i++){
            if(bookItemList.get(i).id == id){
                bookItemList.remove(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```
// Responsibilty of Member class
/*
1. search books by title, author -- dne
2. Reserve a book
3. Return the book
 */

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Member extends Person{

    private List<Reservation> myActiveReservations;


    Member(String name, String phoneNo, String address){
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
        this.address = address;
        this.myActiveReservations = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    public List<BookItem> searchByGenre(Genre bookGenre){
        return Catalog.searchByGenre(bookGenre);
    }

    public List<BookItem> searchByAuthor(String author){
        return Catalog.searchByAuthor(author);
    }

    public boolean reserve(BookItem item){
        // try to create a reservation for it.
        // If successful, add it to the active reservations list and return true
        // If not successful, return false
        Reservation res = Reservation.createReservation(item, this);
        if(res == null){
            System.out.println("Not able to reserve Book");
            return false;
        }
        this.myActiveReservations.add(res);
        System.out.println("Reserved Book");
        return true;
    }

    public void returnBook(Reservation res){

        // fine calculator
        int fine = Payment.fineCalculator(res);
        Reservation.checkout(res);
        myActiveReservations.remove(res);
        System.out.println("Returned Book");
    }

    public List<Reservation> getActiveReservations(){
        return this.myActiveReservations;
    }
}
```

```
/*
This class handles matter related to fine calculation
 */

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class Payment {


    private static int fineRate = 5;

    public static int fineCalculator(Reservation res){
        BookItem item = res.item;

        LocalTime currTime = LocalTime.now();

        if(currTime.isAfter(item.getResEndDate())){
            Duration duration = Duration.between(currTime, item.getResEndDate());
            int days = (int) duration.toDays();
            int fine = days*fineRate;
            System.out.println(" Please pay fine: "+days);
            return fine;
        }

        return 0;
    }

}
```

```
public abstract class Person {
    String name;
    String phoneNo;
    String address;
}
```

```
/*
Class Responsiblity
Create a reservation against a book item and a user

 */

import java.sql.Time;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class Reservation {

     BookItem item;
     Member member;


     // private constructor
     private Reservation(BookItem item, Member member){
         this.item = item;
         this.member = member;
     }

     public static Reservation createReservation(BookItem item, Member member){

         LocalTime currTime = LocalTime.now();

         if(item.getResEndDate().isBefore(currTime)){
             // reservation possible
             // return a reservation object
             item.setResStartdate(currTime);
             item.setResEndDate(currTime.plusHours(24*7));
             return new Reservation(item, member);
         }
         return null;
     }

     public static void checkout(Reservation res){

         BookItem item = res.item;
         LocalTime currTime = LocalTime.now();
         item.setResStartdate(currTime);
         item.setResEndDate(currTime);
     }
}
```

```
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create a library
        String libName  = "UW-Madison";
        Catalog.libName = libName;
//        Library ourLib = Library.getInstance(libName);

        // create admins
        Admin ad1 = new Admin("Pankaj","7896","Madison",libName);

        // create members
        Member m1 = new Member("Pranavi","6758","Atlanta");

        // add books to library
        ad1.addBook(1,"Oscar", Genre.FICTION);
        ad1.addBook(2,"Piastri", Genre.HORROR);
        ad1.addBook(3,"Pedro", Genre.ROMANTIC);

        // search functionality
        List<BookItem> res = m1.searchByAuthor("Piastri");
//        m1.searchByGenre(Genre.FICTION);
//        m1.searchByAuthor("Pankaj");

        // reserving a book
        if(res.size() > 0){
            m1.reserve(res.get(0));
            // print member's active res list
            for(Reservation resItem : m1.getActiveReservations()){
                System.out.println(resItem.item.author +
                        resItem.item.genre+
                        resItem.item.getResStartdate().toString()+
                        resItem.item.getResEndDate().toString()+
                        resItem.member.name
                        );
            }
        }

        m1.returnBook(m1.getActiveReservations().get(0));
        System.out.println(m1.getActiveReservations().size());
    }
}
```

Trying to learn better ways to make my code more modular. Also trying to learn where I can use some design patterns in the code if they make it better.

Comment: Perhaps you should add some prose briefly and specifically explaining the requirements. What is the business problem addressed by this software?

Comment: Those concerns/goals you mention at the very bottom of your Question belong at the top.

Comment: common practice is to have user, role, and permissions...so not saying Admin, Member, Person is wrong but definitely not usual

Answer (score 5):

You said:

> I tried to make classes so that I follow Single Responsibility principle.

See Wikipedia pages, [*Single responsibility principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and [*Separation of concerns*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Your first class `Admin extends Person` violates this principle. You have methods `addBook` and `removeBook` that then passes on the workload to a `Library` object. The `Admin` class should contain state and logic that represents a particular administrator. That class should not know about the bureaucracy of book inventory.

Look at it this way: Suppose you were to expand your software to encompass more of a library's work. Besides adding/removing books from the shelves, an administrator of a library also is involved in daily opening & closing procedures, hiring/firing staff, building maintenance, legal compliance, fire safety inspections, budget planning, generating reports to executives, and so on. Should all that code be added to your `Admin` class? Obviously, no, that would be overwhelming and confusing, making your software difficult to change or maintain. [Object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) is all about organizing code in a way that is intelligible and convenient for humans.

To add and remove books from the library's inventory, create an `Inventory` class with `add` & `remove` methods. Those methods might take an `Admin` object as an argument if the requirements say we need to track which person authorized or executed the addition/removal.